# Laravel foreach inside foreach order everything

Tags: laravel, foreach

I have foreach inside foreach and would like to order everything that is returned by title.

I now have and it works:

```
@foreach ($province->cities->sortBy('title') as $city)
  @foreach ($city->stores->sortBy('title') as $store)
```

But they are first ordered by city title and then by store title, logically. But what I'm trying to achieve is that they are all ordered by store title among themselves, regardless what city they are in.

And I tried something like:

```
@foreach ($province->cities->stores->sortBy('title') as $store)
```

But it doesn't work. What to do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you have the inverse of these relations setup? and i am assuming these relationships have been eager loaded?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function stores(){
  return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Store', 'App\City');
}
```

Got it to work with this in ProvinceController. So sorry for the stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

Potentially you could `pluck` the stores from the cities Collection:

```
$stores = $province->cities->pluck('stores')->sortBy('title');
```

Or just in the loop

```
@foreach ($province->cities->pluck('stores')->sortBy('title') as $store)
```